# Save data filled in multiple fragments together

Tags: android, object, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

Reqirement-I have an activity with three fragments. Each fragment has a form for user to fill and a proceed button.Proceed button will move user to next fragment.On third fragment proceed button will send data filled in the form of all three fragments to server.

Approach- I declared an object in activity.In each fragment when user click on proceed I assign fields of that object with data filled in fragment.When user click on proceed button in third fragment that object is submitted to server.

Is this approach correct? Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) instead if you don't want to maintain an object and want to retain the information the user entered for later use in the app.

Comment: Not good idea as I want that information only for that activity and don't want to persist it across sessions

Comment: Got it, then your approach is fine I think.

Answer (score 0):

Working on main activity thur open fragment. 
Create home activity one static method. and call after one fragment button clicked.

i have attach below step Please check.
1.Home activity create one method.
2.method name create addUserLineInfoFragment
3."A fragment" clicked set this code 
((YourActivityName)getActivity()).addUserLineInfoFragment();
4.Home activity this method "addUserLineInfoFragment" set "B fragment" open code

Comment: What is addUserLineInfoFragment doing? Is your approach different from what I stated in question?